# Counting arrays result in unexpected behaviour

Tags: php

I am stuck.. I don't understand the following behaviour:

```
$qtest= 3;
$testarray[0] = array();
$testarray[1] = array();
$testarray[2][0] = 0;
print_r($testarray);echo "<br>";

for ($s = 0; $s < $qtest; $s++){
    if (count($testarray[$s] > 0 )){
        echo count($testarray[$s]); echo "<br>";
        break;
    }
}
```

I would expect to only see the result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) ) 
1
```

But the result is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) ) 
0
```

Why do I receive the 0 in stead of the 1 ??????
Really appeciate the help!
Thanks

Comment: What the hell is `$outfeedwork`?

Comment: check the line `if (count($testarray[$s]) > 0 ){ ` wrong position of `(`

Comment: Next time create a *minimal* example, and the bug will become obvious.

Comment: @Kohull - Reminds me of `if(trim($sql === '')) {...}` that I saw elsewhere earlier today

Comment: Really appreciated.... took me forever...! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the condition in the if clause wrongly putting the parenthesis after the comparison.

```
$qtest= 3;
$testarray[0] = array();
$testarray[1] = array();
$testarray[2][0] = 0;
print_r($testarray);echo "<br>";

for ($s = 0; $s < $qtest; $s++){
    if (count($testarray[$s]) > 0){
        echo count($testarray[$s]); echo "<br>";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the comparison you are comparing array with 0
if you compare an empty array with 0 as ,

```
$arr = []
$arr > 0 #true
```

it will return true and that is what happened here

You should check `count($testarray[$s]) > 0`

Here is the corrected code

```
$qtest= 3;
$testarray[0] = array();
$testarray[1] = array();
$testarray[2][0] = 0;
print_r($testarray);echo "<br>";

for ($s = 0; $s < $qtest; $s++){
    if (count($testarray[$s]) > 0 ){
        echo count($testarray[$s]); echo "<br>";
        break;
    }
}
```